# Using a static library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, qt-creator

I'm having a hell of a time finding documentation which clearly explains how to use a static library in Qt Creator.

I've created and compiled my static library using Qt Creator (New=>Projects\C++ Library=>Set type to "Statically Linked Library"). It compiles and spits out a ".a file".

The problem I encounter is when I try to use the library. I have another project that would like to use it (#include files in the library, etc) but I don't know the proper way to link with the library or include files from the library.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
LIBS += -L[path to lib] -l[name of lib]
```

Note! that filename of lib: lib[nameOfLib].a  and you have to pass only original part -l[nameOfLib]

Comment: I found the answer at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries shortly after posting it (had been googling stupid stuff about creator rather than just wandering into qmake docs).

I still don't know what the -L or -l mean, but such is the nature of makefiles.. command line gobbl-dee-gook that can easily be parsed into... command line gobble-dee-gook.

RPG's answer is also relevent, the includepath stuff is important.. I marked yours correct because the -L/-l also seem important!

Comment: This didn't work for me but another answer here did, which is right clicking while editing the .pro file and using the "Add Library" UI.

Comment: Don't forget to add the path of the library's headers if these are not in the same directory than the library. In .pro file, add INCLUDEPATH += [path to library's headers]

Answer (score 20):

..from QT project creator

1. goto projectName.pro from left hand side menu
2. type LIBS +=
3. rightClick AddLibrary

Comment: typing `LIBS +=` is not necessary. You can shorten this to 2 steps.

Comment: Actually this is the only solution I could make work out of all the answers. As andrewrk suggested, you don't need to type LIBS +=. All you need is to go to the .pro file, right click, Add Library, and let QtCreator generate the required lines of code (which BTW, on my system [Qt 5.4, Linux], looked fairly different from what was suggested in other answers.)

Comment: Despite doing this, and selecting the correct _static_ library I still kept getting dynamic one linked. The answer by Temac helped.

Answer (score 19):

The variant

```
 LIBS += -L[PATH_TO_LIB_DIR] -l[LIBNAME]
```

doesn't work if you have both static  `libLIBNAME.a` and dynamic `libLIBNAME.so` libs in the same folder `PATH_TO_LIB_DIR`.
In this case on my linux with *QMake v 3.0*
 the dynamic one is linked by default.
To **force linkage with static** one you need to specify it explicitly without any options.

```
LIBS += PATH_TO_LIB_DIR/libLIBNAME.a
```

Comment: I noticed something simliar: If there is a `module.dll` and a `libmodule.a` in the same folder and I include the dll with `-L<path> -l<name>`, I get a multiple definitions error. However, if I delete the static lib file (.a), then it works. Not sure if this was a coincidence or expected behaviour...

Comment: This is the only place someone has explained how to force linker to use .a if .so is found in same directory

Comment: This is the only answer that helped getting static linkage of a library. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

In your project that uses the library make the [LIBS](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) variable point to your lib's path.
To include files from the library, add the library folder to the [INCLUDEPATH](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) and then do a regular #include in your code files.

e.g:

```
# the binary's .pro  
LIBS += c:/mylibs/math.lib
INCLUDEPATH += c:/mylibs
```

**Edited:**
-L tells qmake that the path is a directory that it can search for libraries
-l tells it that the path is a file, but take note of the observation below.

From the qmake docs:

> This variable contains a list of
> libraries to be linked into the
> project. You can use the Unix -l
> (library) and -L (library path) flags
> and qmake will do the correct thing
> with these libraries on Windows
> (namely this means passing the full
> path of the library to the linker).
> The only limitation to this is the
> library must exist, for qmake to find
> which directory a -l lib lives in.
>
> Note: On Windows, specifying libraries
> with the -l option, as in the above
> example, will cause the library with
> the highest version number to be used;
> for example, libmath2.lib could
> potentially be used instead of
> libmathlib. To avoid this ambiguity,
> **we recommend that you explicitly
> specify the library to be used by
> including the .lib file name suffix.**

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.  Here are the links to LIBS and INCLUDEPATH variables from Qt5's docs: [LIBS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs), and [INCLUDEPATH](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath).

Answer (score 2):

Is it

```
LIBS += -L"/some path" -l"somename.a"
```

or

```
LIBS += -L/somepath -lsomename.a
```

or

```
LIBS += -L/somepath -lsomename"
```

This should be as easy as it gets but for some reason it is EXTREMELY hard to pull up a search result for because there are so many hits of forums of people asking for help and I've followed every tip I can get but no help...

Comment: you'll find your answer in Dewfy answer