# Installing C++ libraries(specifically Audiere) on windows?

Tags: c++, qt

Hey this is probably a really easy beginner question but I'm trying to use the library Audiere to play some music files in Qt. I tried to install the library the way the tutorial said(i.e put the header file in MinGw's Include folder.
Yet i Keep getting the same error message:

```
cannot find -laudiered
```

So my main question is can you guys teach me how to install a library on windows? I don't really understand the qmake stuff so i just use the Qtcreator IDE to compile and run my program.
Thanks.

Comment: Check MinGW's `lib` folder for a file called `libaudiered.a` or `audiered.a` or something like that. It could be a `.lib` file too. If those don't exist, you didn't install the library files.

Answer (score 0):

Including the header only provide's the library's declarations, which is fine for the compiler. You're getting a linker error because you haven't told it where to find the library's binary implementation files (.lib for static libraries on Windows).

You need to inform the linker of where to locate the necessary files. Most libraries will provide information on this in their documentation, but you can also try locating them yourself in the library's folders.

I downloaded and had a quick look at Audiere. The file you need to link to is in the /lib folder.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361229/using-a-static-library-in-qt-creator) for how to do it in QT Creator.

Comment: Hey thanks, that really helped. Quick Question, if I have another problem related to this, should i make a new thread?

Comment: @Jonathan If it's a continuation of this question e.g. you tried to follow an answer and got stuck along the way, then you should just comment here. If you've solved the original issue and now you've hit a new problem, then post a new question.