# linking BigTIFF in Qt Project using MSVC C++

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking, libtiff

I have a Qt project, and I would like to save tiff files with 16bit color depth.
Therefore I want to use the bigTIFF library.

On http://bigtiff.org/ site I downloaded

- Source ZIP for libtiff 4.1 including libjpeg 6b and zlib 1.2.3
- Static library ZIP of libtiff.lib 4.1 for MS Windows linked with libjpeg 6b and zlib 1.2.3

The second download contains only **libtiff.lib** and the first one a lot of header and source files.

My idea was now to just include libtiff.lib, the pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = bigTiffTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH = "$$PWD/bigTiffLib/libtiff-4.1/tiff-4.1/libtiff"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/bigTiffLib_static_linked" -llibtiff
DEPENDPATH += "$$PWD/bigTiffLib_static_linked"
```

Into my Qt project, and then include the header files, declaring the functions I want to use. So in my case **tiffio.h**.

But when I am calling functions defined in this header I am getting

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'.
```

So obviously when I am calling functions defined in the header file, the compiler can not find the implementation in the **libtiff.lib** file.

How can I tell the compiler that he has to look for the implementation in the lib file? Any other suggestions how to integrate BigTiff in a Qt project?

Comment: No, -l means you can let away the ending .lib, but libtiff is just the name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361229/using-a-static-library-in-qt-creator

Comment: did you find a solution? i'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: I am using the  freeimage library now: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/intro.html