# QT creator using static library

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to follow qt creators instructions to create static libraries.
https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

it shows the below for lines to include in my libraries .pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

# Input
HEADERS += test.h
SOURCES += test.cpp
```

and for the apps .pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET =
CONFIG += console

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += ../staticLibrary
LIBS += -L../staticLibrary/debug -lstaticLibrary
```

I have

library's .pro

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

SOURCES += test.cpp

HEADERS += test.h
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

app's .pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = TestLink
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp


INCLUDEPATH += ../test  // ADDED BY ME
LIBS += -L../test/debug -ltest  //ADDED BY ME
// LIBS += -L../test/debug -ltest.a  //ALSO TRIED .a
```

My library is test. Both folder, the main app and the library are in the same folder. When I now include the .h

```
#include "test.h"
```

I get

```
C:\CPP\Test\TestLink\main.cpp:3: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'test.h': No such file or directory
```

It seems I am following the isntructions here. What am I missing?

This here also suggests the two lines I added should do the job
[Using a static library in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361229/using-a-static-library-in-qt-creator)

Comment: `Cannot open include file: 'test.h'` is a compiler error, while `LIBS+=` is a linker flag. I think you need INCLUDEPATH - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048098/includepath-in-qmake-project-file-doesnt-work.

Comment: I tried this
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\CPP\\Test\\test
but it also doesn't work
 I see now the error changed to 
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'test.lib'

Comment: and I do not see a test.lib file anywhere in that folder. There is an object file library in
C:\CPP\Test\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug
But including that path also does not help. Is that the file I am looking for?