# How to resolve link error in Qt using Telegram library (Td)

Tags: c++, qt, tdlib

I have encountered with link error while building example app, this one (https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/cpp/td_example.cpp) I created project in Qt creator and added td_example.cpp to project. Also previously I have build 32x Td library from sources using this instruction https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=C%2B%2B .

Td artifacts located in this path K:\QtProjects\Telegram\TelegramDependency\td\tdlib ,
here is located 3 folders (bin, include and lib).

in bin folder located 4 .dll files (libcrypto-1_1.dll, libssl-1_1.dll, tdjson.dll, zlibd1.dll)

in lib folder located (tdactor.lib, tdapi.lib, tdclient.lib, tdcore.lib, tddb.lib, tdjson.lib, tdjson_private.lib, tdjson_static.lib, tdnet.lib, tdsqlite.lib, tdutils.lib)

My project located under this path K:\QtProjects\Telegram\TelegramTestAPP

in  folder TelegramTestAPP i have .pro file with such content.

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++20

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        Logger.cpp \
        main.cpp \

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    Logger.h \
    td_example.h


win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdjson


INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/include
```

i removed main function from td_example.cpp and renamed to td_example.h , after that I included this header file and called it from main.cpp inside main function

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "td_example.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("CLogger"), &Logger::GetInstance());

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);

    TdExample example;
    example.loop();

    return app.exec();
}
```

So the question is, why i get link error
example of error

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall td::td_api::tdlibParameters::tdlibParameters(void)" (??0tdlibParameters@td_api@td@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "class td::tl::unique_ptr<class td::td_api::tdlibParameters> __cdecl td::td_api::make_object<class td::td_api::tdlibParameters>(void)" (??$make_object@VtdlibParameters@td_api@td@@$$V@td_api@td@@YA?AV?$unique_ptr@VtdlibParameters@td_api@td@@@tl@1@XZ)
```

compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ Complier 14.0 (amd64_x86)
I also copied all .dll from bin folder to debug folder (TelegramTestAPP/build/debug)

EDIT
Added all static libraries to .pro file

```
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdapi
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdutils
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdclient
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdnet
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdcore
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdsqlite
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltdactor
win32: LIBS += -L'$$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/' -ltddb


INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/include


win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdcore.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdapi.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdclient.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdutils.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdactor.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tddb.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdnet.lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../TelegramDependency/td/tdlib/lib/tdsqlite.lib

win32: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/' -llibcrypto32MDd
win32: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/' -llibssl32MDd

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL-Win32/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL-Win32/include'
```

new Errors (compiler gcc 32 bit)

```
error: undefined reference to `td::ClientManager::execute(td::tl::unique_ptr<td::td_api::Function>&&)'
debug/TdController.o: In function `ZN12TdControllerC2Ev':
error: undefined reference to `td::td_api::setLogVerbosityLevel::setLogVerbosityLevel(int)'
debug/TdController.o: In function `ZN2td6td_api11make_objectINS0_20setLogVerbosityLevelEJiEEENS_2tl10unique_ptrIT_EEDpOT0_':
error: undefined reference to `vtable for td::td_api::setLogVerbosityLevel'
debug/TdController.o: In function `ZN2td6td_api20setLogVerbosityLevel
```

D1Ev':

Answer (score 0):

I don't know those libs, but according to this https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1tdlib_parameters-members.html the symbol you are missing is from td_api, which is not linked it seems. Did you try to link to other libs, in particular tdapi.lib?

Comment: Hi. thanks for response. I added -ltdapi and it removed error with tdlibParameters but still remained errors with Client , so i have added -ltdclient and appeared new errors, after that I added all .lib files to .pro file and get a lot of new link errors.

Comment: If link errors are unrelated, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Then you may add those errors to your question.

Comment: I made a mistake when added linking to the Telegram library. All this files (tdactor.lib, tdapi.lib, tdclient.lib, tdcore.lib, tddb.lib, tdjson.lib, tdjson_private.lib, tdjson_static.lib, tdnet.lib, tdsqlite.lib, tdutils.lib) is a static libraries, and should link them as static libraries. I have added all those libraries to .pro file.  here is updated .pro file . But I still have some linking errors . I put them above

Comment: Note that even the order may be relevant if libs are static. I also suggest to link with the precise filename including the extension: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361229/427544.